# JQUERY divs slideUp only once but need to slide continuously

Tags: jquery

Hi i am trying to move the divs up with slideUp. the sliding up the divs happens only once, but i want to repeat this process continuously. below is my code. i am thankful if someone helps me.

```
function slidUp() {
    var delayMe = 0;
    $("#carousel div").siblings().each(function () {
        delayMe += 8000;
        $(this).delay(delayMe).slideUp(2000, "linear");
        $(this).find("#carousel div:last").after($(this).find("#carousel div:first"));
    }

    });
}

var run = setInterval(slidUp());
```

HTML:

```
<section id="carousel">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#carousel {
    height:300px;
}
#carousel div {
    width:500px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
}
#carousel div:first-child {
    background-color:#e01783;
}
#carousel div:nth-child(2) {
    background-color:#ff4e00;
}
#carousel div:nth-child(3) {
    background-color:#ffd141;
}
#carousel div:nth-child(4) {
    background-color:#6dcb99;
}
#carousel div:last-child {
    background-color:#e2b87f;
}
```

Comment: So...after all the `<div>` elements have slid up, what do you want to happen? Do you want them going in reverse? Do you want them to reset positions?

Comment: yes Serlite. once all the divs move up i want the animation to start once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, well...it's a little bit unclear on what kind of behaviour you're aiming for, but I'll try to help anyways. Michal was right, your script doesn't cause the `<div>` elements to slide back down after they slide up - I assume this is what you want us to work out for you.

You do need to use `setInterval()`, which requires a time interval as an argument. Additionally, an extra curly brace in your code causes it to not work right off the bat - I'm a bit confused as to why you provided non-functional code, as your question seemed to indicate that it worked.

Anyways, here's a revised script that allows found continuous sliding up and down:

```
var slideTime = 2000;
var delayTime = 8000;

function slidUp() {
    var delayMe = 0;
    $("#carousel div").each(function () {
        delayMe += delayTime;
        $(this).delay(delayMe).slideUp(slideTime, "linear");
    });

    $("#carousel div").each(function () {
        $(this).delay(delayMe).slideDown(slideTime, "linear");
    });
}

slidUp();

var run = setInterval(slidUp, delayTime * 2 * 6);
```

I put the values into variables to make them a little easier to change quickly. The addition to the script basically tacks on a delayed `slideDown()` to all of the elements. The first call to `slidUp()` is just to get it started; subsequent calls are performed by `setInterval()`. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sV2t2/) to show you the code in action. Note that I reduced the delay time to 3000, otherwise it takes a while to see it reverse.

Alternatively, if you want the `<div>` elements to just jump right back into position rather than slide, you could use this script:

```
var slideTime = 2000;
var delayTime = 8000;

function slidUp() {
    $("#carousel div").height(300).show();
    var delayMe = 0;
    $("#carousel div").each(function () {
        delayMe += delayTime;
        $(this).delay(delayMe).slideUp(slideTime, "linear");
    });
}

slidUp();

var run = setInterval(slidUp, delayTime * 6);
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Serlite. i think i am not able to explain you...but i will try to make you understand. how to loop the slideUp animation. i.e i dont want all the divs come to their original position but only the first div has to slide down and from their again the slideup animation should start. hope it make some sense

Comment: Hm, is that not what the first given script does? What aspect of the one-by-one sliding down doesn't fit your vision?

Comment: it is something like slideUp repeat

Comment: Oh, okay! Well, that's great to hear.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set time of interval.

```
var time = 10000; // time in ms
var run = setInterval(slidUp(), time)
```

Also you need to `slideDown()` your div so the animation has a chance to reappear.

```
function slidUp() {
    var delayMe = 0;
    $("#carousel div").siblings().each(function () {
        delayMe += 8000;
        $(this).delay(delayMe).slideUp(2000, "linear");
        $(this).find("#carousel div:last").after($(this).find("#carousel div:first"));
        $(this).slideDown(2000, "linear");
    });
}
```

Comment: Michal if set the time the animation will not run

Comment: Try longer time, so It's summary more than your delays and animation time in function. Also please make jsFiddle so we could test it.

Comment: Because it's designed this way. You need to add `slideDown()` in the function as well.

Comment: if i give slideDown then each div slides up and down but not all the divs slide up and slide down. i created the jsFiddle but not able to run in it.